# MS Access and SQL Server Encryption

Tags: sql, security, ms-access

I am running a MS Access app using a few tables hosted on our native SQL server to facilitate easy integration with PowerBI and other apps.  I am an intermediate MS Access user and new the SQL Server.  I don't store anything critically sensitive in any tables and am happy with our normal security for data at rest.  However, when my app or PowerBI requests data from the server, how is that data protected?  I don't want the increased complexity that comes w/ certificate management and processing time associated with encrypting data.  However, I don't want to be low hanging fruit for attacks when I request data from the server (i.e. attacks in transit).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - security is about three things. Confidentiality, integrity and availability. Confidentiality means, that people are not supposed to see data that is not meant for them. Integrity means, that the data is what you expect it to be (no third party is able to manipulate it). And availability means, that the server is always up and running.

This is a simplification, but just to make the point that security is more than many of us believe. If your server is down, then the security is equal to zero.

Having said that, you wanted to know how to protect the communication channel. Sorry to say that, but the best thing we have right now is TLS, which requires certificate management. Look into this page to understand, how this can be configured: http://dba-datascience.com/ssl-or-tls-encryption-on-sql-server/

If you want to know how to protect your SQL Server even more (beyond the communication channel), look into the CIS Benchmarks available here: https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/. They are very technical (which is good), but may be also confusing a bit when you see it for the first time.

Comment: Marek,

Thanks so much!  Luckily for me, I think I can maneuver around some of the more sticky issues by simply limiting or truncating the data.  On a more broad level, do you know of any good policy resources regard what should and shouldn't be protected and at what level?  In most of the research I've done on this topic, the database administrator is choosing to encrypt some -but not all- data.  How is that determination made?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Usually the data to be protected belongs to someone. This someone (often a company) categorizes the data saying how important or valuable it is. The one that performs the categorization must have a sound understanding of the business and the impact. Usually such thing is done by Information Security Officers, written down in a policy or requirements and passed to the dev team.